# live size in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>  <div id="p_scents">     
<p id="test">
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />    
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
</p> </div> 


$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;

             alert(

                 $("#test > input").size()

             );

                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

if i click then value = 2. this is good. and added new input, but if i again click then value agan = 2, should be = 3. I cant use $i. how can i modified function **size()**, that checked live?

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/u9uhV/6/

Comment: btw: "The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call." http://api.jquery.com/size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still getting 2 because you have appended the new input *outside* of your `#test` paragraph.  Update your `size()` call to check the proper container, by replacing:

```
$("#test > input").size()
```

with

```
scntDiv.find('input').size()
```

Comment: it doesn't work because you have a semi-colon inside your alert statement - just remove it as I have in my edit above (and also here: http://jsfiddle.net/vRpHH/)